# Magento 2.3.0 does not change the language

Tags: cache, language, magento2.3.0, developer-mode

I hope you can help me because no solution I find on the internet works.

Change the user's **language to Spanish** And in the **local configuration** also **to Spanish**.

Clean cache but I can **not get it** to be seen in the **Spanish language**.

I have tried some solutions (switch to developer mode), **re-install the Spanish pack**. But it does not work.

Comment: are you trying language `es_ES`

Comment: Yes, I'm trying es_ES

Comment: Thats great you can create a folder in your theme `i18n` and add this file inside https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-spanish-language-pack/blob/master/es_ES.csv and the run command `php bin:magento cache:clean` from magento root

Comment: also make sure after adding this file run this command to `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_ES`

Comment: Thanks, I followed the steps and the language is still English. Although in the options I have selected Spanish.

Comment: is your spanish is on default store

Comment: Yes, screenshoot: https://prnt.sc/mcm0x4

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands and check

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_ES

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully changed the language. I solved it by disabling all types of cache.

Comment: Disabling all types of cache is not really a solution!

Answer (score 0):

for example we are creating japanese language

firstly download your language pack to magento roor path

then execute the following command

php bin/magento i18n:pack ja_JP.csv ja_JP -m merge -d -vvv

flush & clean cache it will work

check the path:
lib/web/i18n/

it should contain your csv file